# Why does my second div element overlap my first?

Tags: html, css

When I create a new div, the second one, whether it be an image or text. It overlaps the first div container. I figured it may be something to do with the display: flex;, but I'm not sure.  Also I am super new so sorry if this is elementary.

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.container {
  height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: underline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-image {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.container li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="header-image" 
    src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png">
  <ul>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Featured Tea</li>
    <li>Locations</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the theory exactly, but `position: fixed;` is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your container has `positioned: fixed;` assigned to it. If you add a margin to your second div and apply `top: 0` to your container you can push it down without affecting your container element like below:

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.container {
  height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0rem; /* force container to the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: underline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-image {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.container li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: darkgray;
}

div:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  margin-top: 4rem; /*give the second div top margin to push it down */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="header-image" 
    src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png">
  <ul>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Featured Tea</li>
    <li>Locations</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- just remove `position: fixed` form `.container` or if you wants it to be fixed you can add `z-index: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your second div ('Hello' block) overlaps first div(header container), because first div has `position: fixed` style.
When you apply `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` to element, the element is become removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Since div is removed from document flow it doesn't take any space in document, imagine that div is flying on another separate layer.

If you want to keep `position: fixed` property you need to compensate it's height by applying:

`padding-top: 69px` to div's parent -> body.

and

`top: 0` to `.container` to make header stick to the top of the screen;

This way all next elements will have right position from beginning and you will not need to offset each of them.

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

/* HERE */
body {
  padding-top: 69px;
}

.container {
  height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
   /* HERE */
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: underline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-image {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.container li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="header-image" 
    src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png">
  <ul>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Featured Tea</li>
    <li>Locations</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Second Hello</p>
</div>
```